# This is what we should be worring about, we are upvoting CRAP in Ask Ubuntu!

Tags: discussion, voting

This is the exact contrary to "[Should we get worried about in what direction Ask Ubuntu wanders?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7579/169736)". For some reason, a question that has **nothing** to do with Ubuntu in any way or form was upvoted... and I could not help but ask: "why?".

[image]

## This is real vandalism!

The voter is literally **rewarding** a user for a bad... very bad question. The faults on the question are not surprise. I found this *gem* in the 10k Flags flagged as Very Low Quality. How something beyond salvage is awarded with a upvote!? I know the "this is bad but not that bad" kind of upvote, but this kind of question isn't the one that can be awarded with such act.

## PLEASE, STOP UPVOTING CRAP.

We don't do this with bad questions in any way or circumstances:

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Voting, both up and down, is a completely "anonymous" function of the site. In that you can do it either way to your hearts content and vote whichever way you chose. It's your votes.

We are not here to make everyone conform, if someone wants to upvote what appears to be spam then fine. If someone wants to downvote what appears to be an excellent question that's fine as well.

The import thing is the post was deleted and it was deleted rather quickly. I'm sure it was flagged by multiple people and was either automatically removed or one of the human exceptions handlers removed the post.

Which leads me to my final point. All those points will be refunded soon! Because that's just what happens. So upvotes and downvotes, nothing really matters in the end because it was deleted.

I'm really not sure what posting this achieves other than to just rant about this.

Comment: Related bits from chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/conversation/related-bits I agree on votes are anonymous and generally sort themselves out though.  Upvote.

Comment: Wait, are you telling me that I can't *rant*? Then why I post in meta if I can't rant??? [I was so sure that rants were the blood and soul of meta.](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/4566/4009)

Comment: @Braiam Because you are just ranting for the sake of ranting and telling others how to behave?

Comment: @KevinBowen you are mistaking my words. Marco is taking my question as a *rant*, when that was not my intention. I'm doing a reversal about some other question which was *worrying* about a couple of downvotes in a question (which was wrote almost 45 minutes after the question was posted) and I am pointing out something that should be more worrying instead.

Comment: @Braiam No. I don't think that I am. Obviously the community sees value in your contributions and appreciates them. However, I, personally, think that you are being a bit more dramatic than the issue calls for. We have a great group of folks who keep each other honest. It is not perfect, but again, I, personally, think that it works and you are acting like the sky is falling. I wish that I could spend more time here now, but an 80 hour a week job takes precedence. Keep up the good work, but realize we are a fluid bunch. ;-)

Comment: "Voting, both up and down, is a completely "anonymous" function of the site." I got an e-mail asking me to explain my voting pattern :)

Comment: @vasa1: You must have got the email from one of the [Community Managers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do).. Stack Exchange reverses votes if something seems to be abnormal.. So, voting is not completely anonymous - the developers and community managers can view and analyze anything and everything related to SE (which is obvious)... However, our votes are just visible to them - even the moderators of the site cannot view who/when did the user cast his/her votes.

Comment: @Aditya, it was in the context of the number of downvotes I cast and it was not from a Community Manager or a developer.

Comment: @vasa1 That's why I put quotes around anonymous, it makes it a dubious statement. While no one can see you upvotes, the system knows and does routine pattern behavior checks for various forms of cheating, rage voting, and sockpuppeting

Comment: I don't want to argue with people who have contributed so much to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @vasa1: I get what you are talking about... Anyways, I don't know why am I not getting inbox notifications for comments on Meta... Anyone else facing this?

Comment: @KevinBowen if you see my answer below, and [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8007/169736) you will notice that I was talking about that if we are asked to explain our DV, I could raise also a Meta post about upvotes...

Comment: @Aditya if you aren't the post owner, obviously you will not get messages unless pinged with the @

Comment: @Braiam: I obviously know that :-) ... I didn't get inbox notification for the comment made by vasa1 on Dec 24 at 11:34 AM (he did ping me on that one)... The pinging problem has been solved by now - must be a temporary bug...

Answer (score 1):

My question was a satire to the requirement that we explain our downvotes asked in the linked question. Remember that if you receive a downvote but don't find any fault to the post it could be for one of many good reasons... it could be that your solution isn't the most efficient. I don't know...

Since votes are anonymous as Marco pointed, upvotes and downvotes are self explanatory. If any user is asking for explanation first should check their post, and if they don't find anything bad ask around someone that could help to improve them, or leave it as it.